# Trying to pass data to a global object using props, but can't get data to display

Tags: vue.js, components

I'm trying to pass data from a component to a global object. I have my component working but the author is not displaying correctly. Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

```
let store = {
  _author: 'Johnnie Walker',
};

Vue.component('post', {
  template: '#post-template',
  props: ['title', 'author', 'content']
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    author: store,
    title: 'Aging Your Own Whisky',
    content: 'A bunch of steps and a whole lot of content'
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/syed263/yk8L1tru/1/

Comment: author: store._author?

Answer (score 3):

`store` is an object and you have a property called `_author` in it.

Your `data` should be -

```
data: {
  author: store._author,
  title: 'Aging Your Own Whisky',
  content: 'A bunch of steps and a whole lot of content'
}
```

Comment: Here is a forked version of your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xj0mo21/) that has the correct syntax for getting down to the `_author` property of your store object literal.